# Angular Map parses position differently depending on if it's hard-coded or a scope property

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

Given the minimal example below, the two maps end up in different positions; for some reason, the latter ends up in France even though the coordinates are for Stockholm, Sweden.

How do I work around this weirdness?

To reproduce, just copy the following into a html file and run it in your browser (neither jsFiddle nor Plunkr wanted to show the maps...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <map center="59.325, 18.07" zoom="7"></map>
        <map center="map.center" zoom="7"></map>
    </div>

    <script src="../../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMap']);

        app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.map = {
                    center: [59.325, 18.07]
                }
            }
        ]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is cause because the way a directive it's initialize with google maps

Your text "59.325, 18.07" it's loaded on the html, wich means that on directive compile the value it's already there, otherwise, passing the object map.center the way that the directive it's created it wont get the value, the architecture should be refactor just for getting your value from the object, when I was creating my own map directive I found those diferents

This is a slice of my directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IIGZ0jKIFna2adRqxZpx?p=preview

```
mapModule.directive("map", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
   return {
  restrict: "E",
  priority: 2000,
  scope: {
     centerLatitude: "=",
     centerLongitude: "=",
     refresh: "=",
     width: "@",
     height: "@",
     zoom: "&",
     mapTypeId: "@",
     panControl: "@",
     zoomControl: "@",
     scaleControl: "@",
     show: "="
  },
  compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
     return {
        pre: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
           var toResize, toCenter;
           var map;
           var currentMarkers;

           var el = document.createElement("div");
           el.style.width = "100%";
           if (scope.height) {
              el.style.height = scope.height;
           }
           else {
              el.style.height = "450px";
           }
           element.prepend(el);

           carregaMapa();

           // update the control
           function carregaMapa() {

              //// update size
              //if (scope.width) element.width(scope.width);
              //if (scope.height) element.height(scope.height);

              // get map options
              var options =
              {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                 zoom: 3,
                 mapTypeId: "roadmap",
                 //styles: [{ featureType: "all", stylers: [{ hue: "#0000ff" }, { saturation: -75 }] }, { featureType: "poi", elementType: "label", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] }]
                 styles: [{ "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{ "color": "#444444" }] }, { "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [{ "color": "#d7caca" }] }, { "featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "color": "#f2f2f2" }] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "saturation": -100 }, { "lightness": 45 }] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "simplified" }] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }, { "featureType": "transit", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "color": "#d7d2d2" }, { "visibility": "on" }] }]
              };
              if (scope.centerLatitude) options.center = getLocation(scope.centerLatitude, scope.centerLongitude);
              if (scope.zoom()) options.zoom = scope.zoom();
              //if (scope.mapTypeId) options.mapTypeId = scope.mapTypeId;
              //if (scope.panControl) options.panControl = scope.panControl;
              //if (scope.zoomControl) options.zoomControl = scope.zoomControl;
              //if (scope.scaleControl) options.scaleControl = scope.scaleControl;

              // create the map
              map = new google.maps.Map(el, options);
              ctrl.mapaInstacia = map;

              //google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
              //   ctrl.lastBound = map.getBounds();
              //});

           }

           scope.$watch("show", function () {
              if (!angular.isDefined(scope.show))
                 return;

              if (!map || !ctrl.carregado) {
                 ctrl.carregado = true;
                 ctrl.fitBounds();
                 return;
              }

              if (ctrl.eventoZoomAdicionado == false) {
                 ctrl.eventoZoomAdicionado = true;
                 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                    ctrl.lastBound = map.getBounds();
                 });

                 $timeout(function () {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                    ctrl.mapaInstacia.fitBounds(ctrl.lastBound);
                 });
              }

              //bug for some reason, google maps goes to zoom zero
              if (map.getZoom() == 0) {
                 if (ctrl.markers.length > 1) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                       ctrl.fitBounds();
                    }, 400);
                 }
              }
           });
           scope.$watch("refresh", function () {
              if (map && scope.refresh == true) {
                 scope.refresh = false;

                 if (ctrl.markers.length > 1) {
                    ctrl.fitBounds();
                 }
                 else {
                    $timeout(function () {
                       var mapCenter = map.getCenter();
                       var mapZoom = map.getZoom();
                       google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                       map.setZoom(mapZoom);
                       map.setCenter(mapCenter);
                    }, 100);
                 }

              }

           });

           // convert current location to Google maps location
           function getLocation(lat, log) {
              return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, log);
           }
        }
     }
  },
  controller: mapModule.mapController
};
}]);
```